# Picture does not appear after successfully uploading it

Tags: php, html, upload, multipart

so today I was trying to upload photo from admin file to user file. One thing I discovered is that my code works fine, but something is a little bit wrong I don't know where. When I successfully uploaded the picture, the picture didn't appear. But it successfully been uploaded. Could you help me out?

This is the code I used to upload the picture

```
         <?php
          require_once ('db/database.php');

          if(isset($_POST['submit']))
          {
            $name = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
            $t_name = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
            $dir = 'fotovid';
            $kat = $_POST['kat'];
            if(move_uploaded_file($t_name, $dir."/".$name))
            {
              mysqli_select_db($koneksi, 'koneksi_oop');
              $query = "INSERT INTO gallery (id_gambar, kat_gambar, nama_gambar, path) VALUES ('', $kat, '$name', 'fotovid/$name')";
              $res = mysqli_query($koneksi, $query);
              echo "Berhasil upload foto";
            } else {
              echo "Gagal upload foto";
            }

          }
        ?>

        <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="panel"">

                <div align="center" style="padding-top: 100px;">        
                   <!--  <div class="container1" style="background-color: none;margin-bottom: 235px;">
                        <label for="file-input">Upload Video</label>
                            <input type="file" accept=".mp4,.mkv" id = "file-input" style="background-color: none; width: 300px; "><br/>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src = "assets/js/videoJS.js"></script>
                    </div> -->
                     <form action="inputfoto.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="file_upload" /><br/>
                    <label>Kategori</label>
                    <input type="text" name="kat"><br/>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
                </form>  
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

While this is the class where I call 2 categories from database, which is 'Foto' and 'Video'.

```
   <?php
    include ('admin/db/database.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM kategori_gambar";
        $res = mysqli_query($koneksi, $query);
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
        {
    ?>
        <div>
            <fieldset style="margin:0px 40px 100px 40px;">
                <legend>

                    <a href="keluar_gambar.php?kat_gambar=<?= $row['id'];?>">
                        <?php
                            echo $row['nama'];
                         ?>
                    </a>
                </legend>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
```

And the last one is where the output should comes out.

```
                $query = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE kat_gambar =".$_GET['kat_gambar'];

                $res = mysqli_query($koneksi, $query);
            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <?php
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                {
            ?>
                <img src = "<?php echo $row['path']; ?>" width='300px' height= "200px" /><br/>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
```

This is what happened when I tried to insert the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KczT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4e3e.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgmjF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGmyU.png)

Comment: Do you reach the picture by visiting its url in the address bar of a browser?

Comment: I tried, but the picture seems to come out in a weird way,  like this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGmyU.png @whiteletters in blankpapers

Comment: So the url is not the correct address to reach the pictur. Are you sure the photo is correclty uploaded first?

Comment: yes I do, but let me check it out again

Comment: Please to try to get the url of the uploaded picture and put it in the href

Comment: still didn't work

Comment: can you point out in my code which one should I change?  @whitelettersinblankpapers

Comment: Sorry for delay.  Nice to see that you found the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a permission issue. could you please show us the output of the following code.

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)
```

and also check the folder where you tried to upload.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem. It is the directory problem. Anw, thanks for your respond mate.